# Mimicing cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl request which works perfectly fine on my shell. But I tried to do the same on PHP.

Here's my code: (The first comment being the curl syntax which works perfectly fine.But if i try that in PHP. the `curl_exec()` cannot happen? What mistake am i doing here?

```
<?php 
/* 
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' 
--data 'q=%23mozilla' 
--header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="my-key", oauth_nonce="my-nonce", oauth_signature="my-signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1384358463", oauth_token="my-token", oauth_version="1.0"'
*/
$header= 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="my-key", oauth_nonce="my-nonce", oauth_signature="my-signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1384358463", oauth_token="my-token", oauth_version="1.0"';
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23mozilla',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
);



$ch = curl_init() or die('Cannot Curl :/');
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$return = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch)); //Dies here with: "No URL set!"
curl_close($ch);
echo $return;
```

Comment: Instead of `or die('Cannot Exec');` , try `or die(curl_error($ch));`

Comment: @WayneWhitty : Edited the question. It dies with "No URL set!"

Comment: You have a typo in your code, you have to remove the last comma in the $options array. I know, it may not fix your issue, but it won't hurt neither :)

Comment: @bh42 Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @cipher This should work. Can you try removing the `CURLOPT_URL` option and passing it to `curl_init($url)` instead?

Comment: @Jim : That works. But I see differnt results on the terminal and on my browser. The terminal gives the json data as expected whereas the browser gives the json output, but it contains: error information

Comment: Also, I suspect you are coding with warnings switched off.  When I do the above I get:
PHP Warning:  curl_setopt_array(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE arguments in ...test.php on line 14
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() ...\test.php:0
PHP   2. curl_setopt_array() ...\test.php:14

Comment: Use: `$header= array('Authorization: OAuth ....');`

Comment: @RobBaillie I had my warnings on :). But Does that matter?

Comment: @Thrustmaster : perfect. Thanks . It would be my pleasure to accept if you wrote that comment as answer

Comment: You should have warnings on, but you should then listen and respond to them.  Warnings are important and give you information about subtle mistakes / omissions / etc that might not cause immediate problems, but may give you odd behaviour later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Putting my comment as an answer)

[According to the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` should have an array, not a string.

You want the below:

```
$header= array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="my-key", oauth_nonce="my-nonce", oauth_signature="my-signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1384358463", oauth_token="my-token", oauth_version="1.0"');
```